# Powershell @{} Pipeline Error

Tags: powershell

I have two custom powershell functions meant to be used like:

```
Get-Users | Select LoginName | Get-UserJobStatus -StartDate 2013-02-19 -EndDate 2013-02-21
```

When this is ran, I receive an error from the web service:

```
@{LoginName=UserName} not found
```

Which makes sense, because the username that's passed to the web service function should be  just UserName and not @{LoginName=username}. How do I format that correctly?

```
function Global:Get-BackupJobStatus
{
    [cmdletBinding()]

    Param(
      [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        HelpMessage='Specific account name.',
        ParameterSetName='LoginName',
        ValueFromPipeline=$True
      )]
      [System.String[]]$LoginName = $null,

      [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage='Start date for report.'
      )]
      [System.DateTime]$startDate,

      [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage='Ending date for report.'
      )]
      [System.DateTime]$EndDate
    )

    Begin {
      $tempXml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
      Write-Output $StartDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    }

    Process{        
      $tempXml.Load("https://webservicecall/info.do?LoginName="+$LoginName+"&Date="+$startDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    }

    End {
      Write-Output $tempXml.Users.User
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't recognize Get-Users. Where does it come from and what does it output? Regardless, I suspect that you need to change the select to: |Select -ExpandProperty LoginName |

Comment: Get-Users was a custom function I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your function is expecting a `string`-object as the `loginname` input and you are sending a `pscustomobject`(created by `select`) with a **property** called `loginname`. To fix this, use `select-object`'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter to send the value of `loginname`instead of objects with that property. Like this:

```
Get-Users | Select -ExpandProperty LoginName |
    Get-UserJobStatus -StartDate 2013-02-19 -EndDate 2013-02-21
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you could add `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true` to allow you to bind the LoginName property of the object in the pipeline to the $LoginName parameter

Comment: A nice addition to make it more foolproof :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use "ValuefromPipeline", then it needs to be just the value:

```
Get-Users | Select -ExpandProperty LoginName | Get-UserJobStatus -StartDate 2013-02-19 -EndDate 2013-02-21
```